# Android Marshmallow and above version can't trigger USB_DETACHED

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I'm confused on why `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED` from [USB Accessory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html) doesn't triggered in **Marshmallow** and **Nougat** versions but when using pre marshmallow versions I can trigger the broadcast.

My codes are based on the documentation in USB Accessory link above so no need to paste my code, the only thing is it doesn't trigger when using Marshmallow and up versions of android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to mention what device you are testing against. If on a Nexus device it may be a actual bug in which case you may want to submit it by following the steps here https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html and include things like model/build number in the report.

Comment: Yes, i'm using nexus 7 having a 6.0.1 android version. And thanks for your info

Comment: The Nexus 7 (2013) is a 'older' device and won't get Android 7.0. Unfortunately one of things about Android is that using different SOC vendors makes maintenance/upgrade path more of a challenge. Along with the fact that the Android Compatibility Definition Document only list USB Accessory as a 'should' rather than a must for tablets like the Nexus 7 may mean that the drop is support was a compromise the Android team made. EDIT-ah looks like there is a bug as you've linked to it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the linked you've given to me i was able to search that issue that i encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i search the issues in [reports bugs in Google](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html) i was able to find this issue on android firmware so basically it's more like on android OS problem that **UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED** was not triggered.Kindly visit on this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178293).